# OS X go-pear.phar failed to open PEAR/Proxy is not a file in phar

Tags: php, pear

Using Mac OS X Sierra.

Tried to install pear, but causes an error of PEAR/Proxy is not a file in phar. Totally weird. Got ideas guys?

> php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar

```
1-12, 'all' or Enter to continue: 
Beginning install...
Configuration written to /Users/louie/.pearrc...
Initialized registry...
Preparing to install...

installing phar:///Users/louie/Development/project/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Archive_Tar-1.4.2.tar...
installing phar:///Users/louie/Development/project/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Console_Getopt-1.4.1.tar...
installing phar:///Users/louie/Development/project/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/PEAR-1.10.3.tar...
installing phar:///Users/louie/Development/project/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Structures_Graph-1.1.1.tar...
installing phar:///Users/louie/Development/project/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/XML_Util-1.4.2.tar...

PHP Warning:  require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/PEAR/Proxy.php): failed to open stream: phar error: "PEAR/Proxy.php" is not a file in phar "go-pear.phar" in phar:///Users/louie/Development/project/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Downloader.php on line 23

Warning: require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/PEAR/Proxy.php): failed to open stream: phar error: "PEAR/Proxy.php" is not a file in phar "go-pear.phar" in phar:///Users/louie/Development/project/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Downloader.php on line 23
```

Comment: Can also reproduce on Linux.

Comment: Issue with PEAR 1.10.3 - http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=21190

Comment: Same issue on Amazon Linux 2018.3 whatever version is available as of early April 2019

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue. I think something is wrong with the latest release version of pear package. I installed an older one and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

A new file was missing from the phar... that has been corrected in pearweb_phars-1.10.4 just released.  The phars on the pear website are now updated.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, I just got this on 2019 on Amazon linux... following this:https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

Comment: Found your repo: https://github.com/pear/pearweb_phars, let's keep fingers crossed an older version works. Also, what about this?https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/80218/hacking/php-pear-site-hacked.html

Comment: Ok, this commit works:https://github.com/pear/pearweb_phars/blob/2f0340a9bb561bd7dce7f19e837c86520aeb2fac/go-pear.phar